# Prompt for parameter of separate date and time values?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working with Crystal Reports 2016.  The data source is MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am currently able to prompt the user for a date range for my report using a parameter.  I would also like to add a prompt for a time range.  Using a prompt for a DateTime parameter does not do what I want.  The date range is going to select a larger window of days, and the time range will select what times during the day the report will show the data.  Using a DateTime parameter prompt merely adds precision to the start and ending day/time of the report and does not do what I want.  Both the prompts will refer to the same DateTime record in the database.

I have tried adding a separate, second, parameter prompt for the just time, but that has the same result as changing the parameter prompt to a DateTime value.  I will reiterate: that is not my desired result.

As a concrete, specific, example, I would like to use data that is valid for September 1 - October 31 where the thing I am reporting on happened between 2 pm and 10 pm EST on any or all of those days.  If I have a DateTime selection, I can choose September 1, 2 pm and October 31, 10 pm.  However, that is not what I am trying to select.

Basically, select the data that occurred on these days between the time of 2 pm and 10 pm.  Where the start date and end date are selectable; and the start time and end time are selectable.

[image]

Using SQL parlance, I think I would like an inner join of the date range and the time range (the center one):

[image]

A completely unrelated but similar example; this phenomenon is similar to meetings in Outlook.  You could (but should not) make a really long meeting that starts on 1 day/time, and ends on another day/time several days later, but you should make a recurring meeting to properly manage your and your rooms' schedule.  I am looking to select records in a similar fashion to a  recurring meeting.

How can I craft a `select expert` rule to get the data I am looking for?  Is there some other way I can do this?  Maybe a subreport?

Comment: It may be too late, as this Q is a week old now. I would rewrite it as sample inputs, required output and your best attempt at a solution (I know as  CR dev you rely on a lot of embedded widgets, which makes posting more difficult). But as is, I can't visualize what is the problem you're trying to specifically solve. If you say "I'm getting 2017-05-12.00:00:00Z but I want 2017-05-12.23:59:59", then I think a lot of people would find it easier to help. Good luck.

Comment: A simple solution perhaps is to create a database view in MS SQL pointing to the other table where the report gets the data but tell it to only get the values here the [hour] `HH` is between 2 PM and 10 PM using the `DATEPART` function. So for example without being column explicit using `SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE DATEPART(hh,[DateField]) BETWEEN 14 AND 22` in the view and then point the `select expert` report to get it's data for selected date periods from it. Another way would be to make the same T-SQL query a CR SQL Command but an SQL view may perform much better.

Comment: So to be clear the SQL query you may want to play with as an SQL VIEW or a CR SQL Command object would be `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATEPART(hh,[DateField]) BETWEEN 14 AND 22` and you can be column specific with the query in the SQL view so `select column1, column2 FROM ~` etc. instead of `*`.

Comment: My example was a specific example.  I want to let the user determine the start and end times, which is why I mentioned parameters.  I don't know that much about SQL Views, but I'm guessing if I paste something like that somewhere, it's statically set and the user running the report can't change it on the fly.  I'll see about making the question more clear in that regard.

Comment: Okay, that wouldn't work if the users to pick the time range. This may be a job for a stored proc perhaps. I don't have CR anymore and it's been a year or so since I messed with it to test anything but I thought I could help with a potential SQL level solution assuming you could get the CR portion setup and configured to allow the TSQL to do the filtering, etc. Not sure if you could build a stored proc and pass in start and end time parameters and have CR dynamic prompt for those values, etc. but I thought I'd at least give you some ideas... Good luck regardless.